# Split form columns not displaying correct value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a split form set up in Access 2007. In it, I have one combo box to select a school, and the After Update event for this combo box populates a second combo box.

The second combo box selects an item of equipment, and the query associated with it selects all equipment located at the selected school, unioned with the currently selected piece of equipment. (If the school selection changed, the box would turn blank, but actually still hold a value, so I unioned it with it's own current value)

Anyhow, the issue is that the equipment column in the split view only shows equipment values that are associated with the currently selected school as well. For example, if I have a form with schoolA and EquipmentA selected, only equipment also associated with SchoolA will appear in the Equipment column of the split form data sheet. If I change the School column to SchoolB, any rows that were populated with equipment associated with schoolA disappear, and equipment on rows associated with schoolB now show up.

Interestingly, if you click on the school column of the data sheet, this also will update the equipment column to only show equipment related to whatever school was in that row.

To summarize: changing the value of one field in my split form will change what data is displayed in the data sheet portion of the form. Clicking on the fields column in the data sheet has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, as you describe. I used a workaround (i.e. used different control instead of split-form)

My Situation:since In the split-form, I was just showing the records, and not allowing users to edit the records in split form. Users could click on any record in split form, which would show in main form, and then could edit. The main purpose of this form was for the users to be able to search for the data in split form and then select and edit.

My workaround : Created a form, where I used text boxes to search, and a list view to show all the columns which were in the split form. On double click event, I added Open the form filtered with the record which was double clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that working better. But I've put several hours of work into this form and I'm hoping I don't have to start over. I swear it wasn't doing this while I was working on it yesterday, but I can't figure out what I changed that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this but I think it was because my data is linked to an ODBC location.  I went into File-->Options-->Current Database and went down to "Filter lookup options..." then checked ODBC fields.  Then I was able to see drop-down selections.